# Math rounding in c# - whole numbers issue

Tags: c#, rounding

```
<%= Math.Round(keyRate, 5) %>
```

So in our view, we use this to display a bunch of numbers. it seems when we have a whole number, it rounds to 2 decimals instead of 5. Is this expected behavior? If so, how would I change it.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the type of `keyRate`? Could you give an example of the issue?

Comment: keyRate is a decimal in c#. For example, if I have the number 5, it puts '5.00', but if its like 5.78567896 it will put '5.78567'

Comment: Is that just using the default conversion to string? If you could provide a short but complete console app, that would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `Math.Round(d, decimals)` is the number of fractional digits that will be returned *at most*. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx):

> If the precision of d is less than
>   decimals, d is returned **unchanged**.

In your case you are passing a number with less fractional digits, so it remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between what a number **is** and how it's **displayed** when written out.  You may need to override [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2.aspx) with [ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx)

Per the [Custom Numeric Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), if you want it to be 5 places, you would use

```
Math.Round(keyRate, 5).ToString(00.00000)
```

[More information on the "0" custom specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Specifier0).

Comment: +1 was looking for that format string - also if this is just for display purposes might as well get rid of the `Math.Round()` altogether then.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that it is rounding to 2 decimals while you are passing a whole number? My guess is that you are outputting only 2 decimals.

Comment: Well how can I get it to display out to 5 decimals no matter what?

Comment: String.Format("000.00000", roundedKeyRate)